# Чередование регистра

Tags: javascript, строки

Всем привет, ребята помогите решить задачу.
Суть, у меня есть строка, и мне нужно сделать так, что бы верхний регистр всегда менялся на нижний, а нижний на верхний.
Пример было : HeLllO wOrrLd;
Стало : hElLo WoRRld;

```js
let str ='HeLlo WoRlD';
let str2 = ' ';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
if (str.match(/[A-Z]/g) && str.match(/[a-z]/g)) {
  str2 = str2 + str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
  str2 = str2 + str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
}
} console.log(str2);
```

Получаеться плохо, т. к. строки с разными регистрами накладываються друг на друга.

Сижу уже целый день, ни как не могу понять, буду рад за помощь и объяснение, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы в строке искали символы нижнего регистра и верхнего и независимо ни от чего добавляли и нижний регистр, и верхний. Бесмысленно.

```js
let str ='HeLlo WoRlD';
let str2 = '';

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].match(/[A-Z]/)) {
    str2 += str[i].toLowerCase();
  } 
  else if (str[i].match(/[a-z]/)) {
    str2 += str[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  else {str2 += str[i]};
} 
console.log(str2);
```

Также подумайте над тем, что есть варианты эффективнее regexp.

Comment: Огромное, спасибо!

Comment: Так на любых лишних символах можно вызывать смену регистра - хуже им от этого не будет.

Answer (score 3):

```js
console.log("HeLlo WoRlD".replace(/./g, c => {
  var u = c.toUpperCase()
  return c === u ? c.toLowerCase() : u
}));
```

Comment: Примного благодарен!

Comment: Ваш вариант лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Если буквы только латинские:

```js
console.log("HeLlo WoRlD".replace(/([a-z])|([A-Z])/g, (m,l,u) => u ? m.toLowerCase() : m.toUpperCase()));
```